# Forward a file from one API to the next in postman

Tags: file, postman

**Context:**

- I'm trying to migrate as cleanly from one ticketing service to the another.
- Some tickets have attachment files, I get direct links to those files.

Using postman and the direct link to the file, I can `get` the raw data of the attachment files, and send it to the API of the other server. But I can't seem to do this correctly, always getting bad requests.

```json
[
    {
        "ticket_id": 123,
        "filename": "filename.docx",
        "datecreated": "2023-09-28T08:08:07Z",
        "filesize": 432777,
        "data":"very very long string with data" // (Not even sure if it's base_64 encoded, it's lots of ����)
    }
]
```

Comment: What does the API specification for the new API request tell you it needs?  What does the API specification for the existing API response tell you it returns?  You then need to match the two together.  If you don't know what something returns, check the specification.

Comment: Sadly the specification isn't very specific, I wanted to check if I'm doing something very dumb by just posting a string with lots of data without formatting it in any specific way. 
The specification only tells me it should be posted in base64 format. I'm unsure if the string I got back is actually base64, any ideas how to check that?

Comment: Yes, use one of the online base64 decoders.  If it can decode the string then its base 64.